# How to calculate the orientation of a point at another point in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have two point layers，name "1" and name "2"，The points in layer 2 have some offset relative to layer 1.
[image]

I want to generate a field to display the angle at which the points in layer 2 are offset from layer 1.
like this:

[image]

How should I operate it.

Comment: How do you know which point from layer 2 should be used for a point on layer 1?

Comment: Adjacent points

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will search for the nearest point within 1000 m (the unit of my crs is meters), and calculate the azimuth:

```
round(degrees(
azimuth(point_a:=$geometry, point_b:=
overlay_nearest( layer:='secondlayer', 
expression:=$geometry, limit:=1, max_distance:=1000)[0])))
```

If you want to create a field with the value you can use [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator). I just label the points using the expression:

[image]

Comment: If you need to take the ellipsoid and CRS in account, you can also use the bearing function (new since QGIS 3.34.0): bearing(point_a,point_b[,source_crs][,ellipsoid])